# Sending Email Using Code vs Sending Email Using Profile

Tags: sql-server, c#

I am just testing with email on the same server using SQL Server profile and .NET Application.

.NET application is sending email successfully,

```
string smtpServer = "smtp.gmail.com";
int smtpPort = 587; // Update the port accordingly
string smtpUsername = "xxxxxku07@gmail.com";
string smtpPassword = "xxxxx";

// Set the sender's and recipient's email addresses
string fromEmail = "xxxxxku07@gmail.com";
string toEmail = "xxxxxku07@gmail.com";

// Create a MailMessage object
MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage(fromEmail, toEmail);
mailMessage.Subject = "Subject of the email";
mailMessage.Body = "Body of the email";

// Create a SmtpClient instance
SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient(smtpServer);
smtpClient.Port = smtpPort;
smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(smtpUsername, smtpPassword);
smtpClient.EnableSsl = true; // Set to true if your SMTP server requires SSL/TLS
try
{
    // Send the email
    smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
    Console.WriteLine("Email sent successfully!");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error sending email: " + ex.Message);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

and SQL Server using the same configuration as above C# code.

[image]

When I do this in SQL Server,

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @profile_name = 'xxxxGmailAmtAccount',
    @recipients = 'xxxx@gmail.com',
    @subject = 'Test Email',
    @body = 'This is a test email from SQL Server';
```

I get this error in logs,

> The mail could not be sent to the recipients because of the mail server failure. (Sending Mail using Account 3 (2024-01-08T14:33:09). Exception Message: Cannot send mails to mail server. (Failure sending mail.).

I don't get why .NET is able to send email while SQL Server not on the same server?

Comment: The fact that mail via .Net works proves that 1) there is no networking issue and 2) mail credentials are good. Unfortunately DBMail is a ...mess. Start with [troubleshooting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/database-mail/database-mail-general-troubleshooting?view=sql-server-ver16) steps.